# Java - stream of bytes vs. stream of characters?

Tags: java, stream, char, byte

Title is pretty self-explanatory. In a lot of the JRE javadocs I see the phrases "*stream of bytes*" and "*stream of characters*" all over the place.

**But aren't they the same thing?** Or are they slightly different (e.g. interpreted differently) in Java-land? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Java, a `byte` is not the same thing as a `char`. Therefore a byte stream is different from a character stream. Bytes are intended for arbitrary binary data; characters are specifically for data representing the building blocks of strings.

> but if a char is only 1 byte in width

Except that **it's not.**
As per [the JLS §4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) a `char` is a number in the range:

> from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

But a `byte` is a number in the range

> from -128 to 127, inclusive

Comment: Thanks @Matt Ball - I understand they are different as far as types go (`byte`, `char`, etc.), but if a `char` is only 1 byte in width, then what's different about storing an input stream as a byte array vs char array? That was at the root of my question.

Comment: Who says a `char` is only 1 byte in width? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Answer (score 7):

Stream of byte is just plain byte, like how you would see it when you open a file in HEX Editor.

Character is different from just plain byte. ASCII encoding uses exactly 1 byte per character, but that is not true for many other encoding. For example, [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) may use from 1 to 4 bytes to encode a single character. Stream of character is designed to abstract away the underlying encoding, and produce `char` of one type of encoding (in Java, `char` and `String` uses UTF-16 encoding).

As a rule of thumb:

- When you are dealing with text, you must use stream of character to decode the byte into character with the appropriate encoding.
- When you are dealing with binary data or mixed of binary and text, you must use stream of byte, since it doesn't make sense otherwise. If a sequence of byte represents a String in certain encoding, then you can always pick those bytes out and use [`String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) constructor to get back the String.

Answer (score 5):

They are different. `char` is a 2-byte datatype in Java: `byte` is a 1-byte datatype.

Edit: `char` is also an unsigned type, while `byte` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is better off to talk about streams in terms of their sizes, rather than what they carry. Stream of bytes is more intuitive than streams of chars, because streams of chars make us have to double check that a char is indeed a byte, not a unicode char, or anything fancy.

A char is a representation, which can be represented by a byte, but a byte is always going to be a byte. All world will burn when bytes will stop being 8 bits.

Comment: _"All world will burn when bytes will stop being 8 bits."_ Hardly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#History